# Why carousel of materialize css and *ngFor not working together dynamicaly to get images

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, materialize

I'm trying to materialize angular code for carousel. The carousel is associated to a dynamic array but when i use `*ngFor` with carousel class its not working.

I tried writing the `class="carousel-item"` inside for loop but console shows:

> Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of undefined.

This code not working:

**Template:**

```html
<div class="carousel carousel-slider">
    <div class="carousel-item" href="#one!">
       <div *ngFor ="let item of items;let i = index">
           <img src={{items[i]}}>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Component:**

```js
options = {fullWidth: false};

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
    var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems, this.options);
}
```

I'm only getting one image that too which is cropped in half where as if i remove the for loop and write `<div class="carousel-item">` one after the other like:

```html
<a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src={{items[0]}}></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src={{items[1]}}></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src={{items[2]}}></a>
```

Doing this, I get the carousel working but it is not binded to a dynamic array which is what i want.

Comment: You should try to make your dynamic template match the expected static result. You may try this: `<a class="carousel-item" *ngFor ="let item of items;let i = index" [href]="i">
   <img src={{ item }}>
  </a>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of initialising the carousel in `OnInit` use the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
// other imports

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  // ...

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
    var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems, this.options);
  }
}
```

In addition change your template like this:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#{{hrefs[i]}}!" *ngFor="let item of items;let i = index">
        <img src={{item}}/>
    </a>
</div>
```

`*ngFor` on the a-tag will create the structure required by materialize.

Using the index of the current element and a new array called 'hrefs', the href attribute is set individually for each a-tag.

Please checkout this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-materialize-carousel) for a working example.

**Edit: With API response**

The error "Can not read property 'clientWidth' of undefined" appears now (as well as during the initialization of the carousel within OnInit), because at the time the `M.Carousel.init (...)` is called the HTML structure is not complete yet. As long as `this.items` is undefined, there are no a-tags with class `carousel-item`.

To work around the problem, the initialization of the materialize carousel must be delayed until the data is loaded from the server and all a-tags were added to the DOM by `*ngFor`.

```
// removed code because it wasn't the best solution..
// it's still in the Stackblitz as comment
```

**Edit #2**

I just realized that there is a better method: instead of setting a timeout on the initialization of the carousel, let the `*ngFor` trigger the init after it's done adding the last item to the DOM. To do so, change your html like this:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#{{hrefs[i]}}!" *ngFor="let item of items;let i = index; let last = last">
        <img src={{item}}/>
    <ng-container *ngIf="last">{{initCarousel()}}</ng-container>
  </a>
</div>
```

In your component you will only need the following now:

```
// imports
// ...

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  // ...

  ngOnInit() {
    // dummy api request
    this.fakeApiRequest().pipe(delay(2000)).subscribe((res) => {
      // parse api response
      this.items = res;
    });
  }

  initCarousel() {
    // timeout needed, otherwise navigation won't work.
    setTimeout(() => {
       let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
       let instances = M.Carousel.init(elems, this.options);
    }, 100);
  }

  fakeApiRequest(): Observable<string[]> {
    return of(["https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0", "https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1", "https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=2", "https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=3", "https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=4"]);
  }
}
```

Adjusted [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-materialize-carousel-async).

Comment: hi thanks for the reply i'm using the items array which takes data from an api using subscribe and it is inside ngOnInit..your code works but im still getting the same error client width undefined.
i tried using boolean check showCarousel with if condition on template then the carosuel doesn't appear but the error is also not shown
 this.getItems().subscribe((res) => {
      this.response = res;
       this.response.forEach((entry) => {
         if (entry.url && entry.description) {
        this.items.splice(0, 0, entry.url);
        this.showCarousel = true;}

Comment: @SurajSharma please check if my edited answer now solves your problem.

Comment: @SurajSharma I had another idea, please check out my modified answer.

Comment: i tried both of your codes, the second one is working like a charm with the data loaded subject and the third variant the images are appearing but iam not able to slide/move the carousel .The second variant can be marked as a solution i think.thanks again @coreuter :)

Comment: @SurajSharma I've fixed the third variant. It needed a `setTimeout` as well (check the last Stackblitz). You have to [close your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) yourself by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Async problems should never be solved with a timeout. Bad answer